# replace value in multi dimensional array with another value in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, I have an array as follows:

```
array(35) {
[0] => array(11) {
'dept_number' → str•4 '2310'
'dept_descr' → str•10 'Some Stuff'
}

[1] => array(11) {
'dept_number' → str•4 '1010'
'dept_descr' → str•11 'Other Stuff'
}
...and so on
```

I have another array as follows:

```
array(22) {
[2310] => str•6 'Bakery'
[1010] => str•4 'Beer'
...and so on
```

I want to replace the dept_descr in the first array with the description in the second array, where the dept_number in the first array matches the key in the second array.  so, the result would be:

```
array(35) {
[0] => array(11) {
'dept_number' → str•4 '2310'
'dept_descr' → str•6 'Bakery'
}

[1] => array(11) {
'dept_number' → str•4 '1010'
'dept_descr' → str•4 'Beer'
}
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach($array(22) as $key=>$value{
      foreach ($array(35) as $target){
         if($target['dept_number'] == $key) $target['dept_descr'] = $value.
      }
}
```

The names $array(22) and $array(35) are not real names. Replace these with the correct names of the arrays.

Comment: this worked!  i added a missing ) on the first foreach, and put a & here: foreach ($array(35) as &$target){

Comment: Glad I could help. I am no longer an accepted answer virgin. Although, I would look more closely at the answers George and Murat posted. They are much cleaner. Not sure why you would be getting a NULL with it though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$original = array(
    array(
        'dept_number' => 2310,
        'dept_descr' => 'Some Stuff'),
    array(
        'dept_number' => 1010,
        'dept_descr' => 'Other Stuff'));

$descriptions = array(
    2310 => 'Bakery',
    1010 => 'Beer');

foreach($original as &$element) {
    $element['dept_descr'] = $descriptions[$element['dept_number']];
}

print_r($original);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dept_number] => 2310
            [dept_descr] => Bakery
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dept_number] => 1010
            [dept_descr] => Beer
        )
)
```

Comment: Are you using/did you replace my `$original` and `$descriptions` arrays properly? Put your code on Pastebin, post a link and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$array1 = ...; // Your first array
$array2 = ...; // Your second array

function descReplace(&$item) {
    $item['dept_descr'] = $array2[$item['dept_number']];
}

array_walk($array1, 'descReplace');
```

Comment: same here, i'm getting a null value for dept_desc in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array(35) {
    [0] => array(11) {
    'dept_number' ? str•4 '2310'
    'dept_descr' ? str•10 'Some Stuff'
    }

    [1] => array(11) {
    'dept_number' ? str•4 '1010'
    'dept_descr' ? str•11 'Other Stuff'
    }
}
$arr2 = array(22) {
    [2310] => str•6 'Bakery'
    [1010] => str•4 'Beer'
}

$arr2Keys = array_keys ($arr2);
foreach ($arr1 as $data) {
    if(in_array($data['dept_number'], $arr2Keys)) {
        $data['dept_descr'] = $arr2[$data['dept_number']];
    }
}
```